# Preventing a particular Component Template from adding Experience Manager markup

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, 2013-sp1

I have a particular Dynamic Component Template, which should not have inline editing features. I don't have any XPM markup in the CT, and I have unchecked the **Enable For Inline Editing** checkbox on the CT, however the `<span><!-- Start Component Presentation:...` markup is still added by the **Enable Inline Editing for Content TBB** (this is added by standard to my CT Finish Actions TBB). Did I miss something? I checked the [online docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=chm&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1389691148617&currentQuery=chm&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-89E8FCF0-009B-4DE3-90E6-26F964948CCE&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-89E8FCF0-009B-4DE3-90E6-26F964948CCE.xml&docid=GUID-89E8FCF0-009B-4DE3-90E6-26F964948CCE&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=) [login required] but it only talks about configuring particular schema fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should remove the `Enable Component Inline Editing` TBB from your Dynamic Template.

Comment: I think indeed the markup will always be generated. The check-box on the CT is checked at runtime, if you would turn that ON now, it would work immediately because the markup would already exist in the CP. Otherwise you'd have to republish.

Comment: Indeed. The TBB checks the render mode and the setting on the Publication Target. It does not check the setting on the TBB - that's done at runtime as you said.

Comment: Ah - so the checkboxes do not influence the markup generation, but rather whether the fields appear as editable in XPM - interesting... is this the same for the checkbox on the Page Template?

Comment: As a sugestion, and if you don't want to remove the Default finish actions in your CT, you can also strip those tags with an additional TBB that is executed after the default finish actions and add that to the CT.